# Meaning of "Contained" and "Merged" in Magit

Tags: git, magit

When I look at a commit in magit, I see:

```
Author:     My Name
AuthorDate: A Date
Commit:     My Name again
CommitDate: A Date

Parent:     20f412c1 Commit message
Merged:     master
Contained:  devel foo
```

I know that 'parent' is the previous commit in the history, but what is the meaning of `merged` and `contained`? I've searched through git & magit docs but they are difficult keywords to search for as they pop up all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you are issuing the command `magit-show-commit`. This function is part of [`magit-diff.el`](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-diff.el). In that file, we can see that for the keywords `Contained` and `Merged`, they are used as parameters to something called `magit--insert-related-refs/magit-buffer-revision`.

The diffing that is happening is described by the magit [documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Revision-Buffer) as:

> User Option: magit-revision-insert-related-refs
>
> Whether to show related branches in revision buffers.
>
> - `nil` Don’t show any related branches.
> - `t` Show related local branches.
> - `all` Show related local and remote branches.
> - `mixed` Show all containing branches and local merged branches.

If we look at the `mixed` option, I interpret it in the following:

For `Contained` this means that as you pick the commit you want to look at, all branches that follow that commit (are contained after it), shall be placed in that section.

For `Merged` this means that it will show all local branches that are merged before this commit.

Comment: Hey - thanks for diving into the lisp for me! If I understand you correctly, the short answer is: 'Contained' branches are the branches which contain this commit, whereas 'Merged' branches are those which were previously merged into the branch on which this commit was made. Thanks for your help!